# Twisted import in python 3

Tags: python, twisted

i have problem with import module name twisted.internet in pycharm it's say:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hamza/PYTHON/twisted1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, endpoints
ImportError: No module named internet
```

so i thought that problem was in python 2.7 so i change my environment to python 3.5.2  and nothing change please help me 
[this is my screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZcLl.png)

Comment: In short, you've named your own module `twisted.py` which is shadowing the actual module `twisted` you are trying to import, which is causing the issue. You need to rename your own module. It should not be `twisted` or any name that will clash with any of the modules you will use.

Comment: You have another module called `twisted` in the same directory as `twisted1.py`

Comment: thanks guys i change my twisted1.py file to another name